# Jenkins updates from SVN but does not update .war file

Tags: svn, jenkins

I'm trying to deploy an application with Jenkins v. 1.529 (Subversion plugin pinned - v. 1.50)
Jenkins detects changes on my SVN

```
    Updating http://svn.mysite.com/myapp/trunk at revision '2013-10-17T11:10:41.062 -0300'
U         src/main/java/br/com/mysite/client/ui/CClass.java
At revision 598
[trunk] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3/bin/mvn -DSVN_TAG=trunk clean
[INFO] Scanning for projectscode here
```

But my application "war file" is the old one.
When I "run" my application, it does not detect the last changes I made.

I've tried all jenkins options, no success:
* Use 'svn update' as much as possible
* Always check out a fresh copy
* Emulate clean checkout by first deleting unversioned/ignored files, then 'svn update'
* Use 'svn update' as much as possible, with 'svn revert' before update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rm -rf /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/myapp/workspace/trunk/*

Answer (score 2):

```
[trunk] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3/bin/mvn -DSVN_TAG=trunk clean
```

If this line is from you actual output, then you only run a clean. I would suggest to also at least run the package phase (build will only compile but not create the new war). I usually go for install.

Comment: Sorry, It is just the begining log,
after that I do "install" and "deploy"

(...)
[trunk] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3/bin/mvn -DSVN_TAG=trunk install
(...)
[trunk] $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3/bin/mvn -DSVN_TAG=trunk deploy

Comment: Do you only deploy to the Repo or also to the application server?

Comment: I deploy to the App Server.

Comment: `mvn -DSVN_TAG=trunk deploy` does not deploy to the app server. Please add more detail on what you do to the question.